# Extra TCP connections on the RabbitMQ server after resource alarm

Tags: rabbitmq, haproxy

I have RabbitMQ Server 3.6.0 installed on Windows (I know it's time to upgrade, I've already done that on the other server node).

Heartbeats are enabled on both server and client side (heartbeat interval 60s).

I have had a resource alarm (RAM limit), and after that I have observed the raise of amount of TCP connections to RMQ Server.

At the moment there're 18000 connections while normal amount is 6000.

Via management plugin I can see there is a lot of connections with 0 channels, while our "normal" connection have at least 1 channel.

And even RMQ Server restart won't help: all connections would re-establish.

1. Does that mean all of them are really alive?

Similar issue was described here https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/384, but as I can see it was fixed exactly in v3.6.0.

2. Do I understand right that before RMQ Server v3.6.0 the behavior after resource alarm was like that: several TCP connections could hang on server side per 1 real client autorecovery connection?

Maybe important: we have haProxy between the server and the clients.

3. Could haProxy be an explanation for this extra connections? Maybe it prevents client from receiving a signal the connection was closed due to resource alarm?

Comment: It sounds like your clients have zombie connections, probably due to poor resource management. 1. What RabbitMQ client are you using? and 2. What happens if you manually kill one of your client processes? Do you see one connection disappear or several? I think you can rule out haProxy as it's just a pass-through. For the connection to be recognized by the broker, it's got to go through a handshake, which is a deliberate process and cannot happen inadvertently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to reproduce the problem: in the end it was a bug in the way our client used RMQ connections.
It created 1 auto-recovery connection (that's all fine with that) **and** sometimes it created a separate simple connection for "temporary" purposes.

Step to reproduce my problem were:

1. Reach memory alarm in RabbitMQ (e.g. set up an easily reached RAM
   limit and push a lot of big messages). Connections would be in state
   "blocking".
2. Start sending message from our client with this new "temp" connection.
3. Ensure the connection is in state "blocked".
4. **Without eliminating** resource alarm, restart RabbitMQ node.
5. The "temp" connection itself was here! Despite the fact auto-recovery
   was not enabled for it. And it continued sending heartbeats so the
   server didn't close it.

We will fix the client to use one and the only connection always.
Plus we of course will upgrade Erlang.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Are all of them alive?

Only you can answer this, but I would ask - how is it that you are ending up with  many thousands of connections? Really, you should only create one connection per logical process. So if you really have 6,000 logical processes connecting to the server, that might be a reason for that many connections, but in my opinion, you're well beyond reasonable design limits even in that case.

To check, see how many connections decrease when you kill one of your logical processes.

> 2. Do I understand right that before RMQ Server v3.6.0 the behavior after resource alarm was like that: several TCP connections could hang on server side per 1 real client autorecovery connection?

As far as I can tell, yes. It looks like the developer in this case ran across a [common problem in sockets](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html), and that is the detection of dropped connections. If I had a dollar for every time someone misunderstood how TCP works, I'd have more money than Bezos. So, what they found is that someone made some bad assumptions, when actually read or write is required to detect a dead socket, and the developer wrote code to (attempt) to handle it properly. It is important to note that this does not look like a very comprehensive fix, so if the conceptual design problem had been introduced to another part of the code, then this bug might still be around in some form. Searching for bug reports might give you a more detailed answer, or asking someone on that support list.

> 3. Could haProxy be an explanation for this extra connections?

That depends. In theory, haProxy as is just a pass-through. For the connection to be recognized by the broker, it's got to go through a handshake, which is a deliberate process and cannot happen inadvertently. Closing a connection also requires a handshake, which is where haProxy might be the culprit. If haProxy thinks the connection is dead and drops it without that process, then it could be a contributing cause. But it is not in and of itself making these new connections.

Comment: > Really, you should only create one connection per logical process.
That was one of the problems. It wasn't guaranteed by our client app.
>  In theory, haProxy as is just a pass-through. 
You are right: in the end, haProxy was innocent in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended that this user upgrade from Erlang 18, which has known TCP connection issues -

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/R3700QdIVJs/taDYKI6bAgAJ